# NPM - Does installing a sub-dependency increase the size of your package bundle?

Tags: npm, package.json

I have a React app. (though for the purposes of this question, the tech doesn't matter)

One of the dependencies is the `material-ui` library.

A dependency of the `material-ui` library is the `react-transition-group` library.

Does this then mean that I can "npm install" the `react-transition-group` library without increasing the size of my JS bundle at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the versions of `react-transition-group` that are used. npm will do it's best to install only a single version of a module. Modern bundlers (Webpack/Rollup) will also try to use a single version inside the bundle.

So when will it use a single instance and when will you get 2 copies?

**Version Ranges overlap:**

`material-ui` requires version `~1.1.0`

Your `package.json` requires version `^1.0.0`

Since those ranges overlap, npm can install any version that matches `1.1.*` and it will work for both modules, and you'll get only 1 copy.

**Version Ranges don't overlap:**

`material-ui` requires version `~1.1.0`

Your `package.json` requires version `^2.0.0`

Since those ranges require different SemVer major versions, npm will install two copies, one to fulfill each requirement. The bundler will also need to bring in both versions.

It can be hard to tell exactly what version exists in a sub-dependency, but you can see them all by running `npm ls` after running `npm install` it will show you all packages and version that are installed in the project.